# Soap offline local network python

Tags: python-3.x, offline, soap-client, zeep

In my python program, I call a SOAP api via Zeep and Zeep Client.

My code works when I have internet connection but not offline. In fact, I have downloaded my WSDL and I am using the same code  in local (without internet) but it's not working.

Does zip work offline?
If not, are there are other solutions? ( I can't install [Suds](https://pypi.org/project/suds/) )

Comment: According to this thread https://superuser.com/a/400770/1132403, yes, you can run a local server even without internet connection. But I guess your WSDL will work only if it does not require resources that it gets through external IPs (see the image on the thread). You maybe should change your WSDL files so that they get resources on local server. Maybe edit the answer and add some information about your WSDL files (be sure to mask sensitive data)

Comment: Do you understand how a SOAP web service works and what the difference is between the service itself and the WSDL of the service? From how you phrased the question it seems to me you are confusing the service with the WSDL. [They are different things](https://d-petre-bogdan.medium.com/the-wsdl-is-not-the-soap-web-service-97f307c4a90b). If that is indeed your understanding, then downloading the WSDL locally or running zeep offline won't work if the service you are invoking is actually accessible from the internet.